# react native image not loading with concatenated string

Tags: react-native

I am using react native and I have tried two pieces of code, the first one does not work and the second one does.  Can anyone explain why?

1. `<Image source={require('../assets/'+'g'+'Light.png')} 
                      style={styles.greenLight}/>`
2. `<Image source={require('../assets/gLight.png')}`

Comment: Not sure why, but I've had a similar issue. I solved it by passing a function that concatenates the string into the image source require statement.

Comment: This is so frustrating. If I understand correctly, passing an array with images names and concatenating them to the correct relative path is not possible? This is possible in almost any modern programming language (and old as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dynamic naming in React Native is not allowed. You should use a switch, if statement or a different function which will do this for you:

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

More information here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html